# Retrieve messages from AMS enabled IBM web sphere MQ

Tags: c#, encryption, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-ams

I'm trying to achieve message security with AMS

I have two users one is a domain user xxx\herath (192.168.10.1)
other user is a local user in my websphere mq server machine (192.168.10.2) wmqserver\bobmquser.

I log in to wmqserver mcahine as a wmqserver\dilantha , This user is a member of Administrator,mqm and users  user groups.

So I followed the instructions from following link
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014690_.htm

I created self-signed certificates and exchanged with both users

[image: client side certificate]

[image: server side certificate]

Then created .mqs folders in their respective locations and added these things

```
wmqserver\bobmquser's keystore.conf
     cms.keystore = D:\AMSKeyRepo\key 
     cms.certificate = Bobmquser_Cert

xxx\herath's keystore.conf 
    cms.keystore = D:\AMSKeyRepo\key
    cms.certificate = Herath_Cert
```

Set the security policies 
[image]
[image]
[image]

and then 
setmqaut -m QM_AMSTest -t queue -n SYSTEM.PROTECTION.POLICY.QUEUE -p musr_mqadmin -p bobmquser +browse

setmqaut -m QM_AMSTest -t queue -n SYSTEM.PROTECTION.ERROR.QUEUE -p musr_mqadmin -p bobmquser +put

When I try to retrieve messages by using "amqsget XYZ QM_AMSTest" as wmqserver\bobmquser ,I'm getting following errors.
[image]

but if I use MQExplorer UI, then I'm able to see these messages. I checked error log files in both client and server and I couldn't find anything. I already googled for reason code 2110 but I'm not able to find suitable solution for this issue.

So anyone can pointing me how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `mqrc 2110` or look it up in the Knowledge centre.

[MQRC_FORMAT_ERROR](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041710_.htm)

Are you on latest maintenance?

Comment: I'm trying to implement AMS in my project.I checked my insert code and found out I didn't set the new MQMessage().Format. So in my read code I'm getting this format as MQFMT_NONE and also, to insert a message I had used WriteUTF(stringMsg) method but in my reading part I'm using ReadString(). So I changed insert method to WriteString(stringMsg) and new MQMessage().Format =  MQC.MQFMT_STRING. Now I'm able to get message as it is. So also it is working fine with amqsget command. Thank you for the error link.